# Why property "sonar.profile" marked as deprecated?

Tags: sonarqube

I am looking for a Sonar Property to attach the quality profile during the build. In previous versions of Sonar there was a property -Dsonar.profile which is deprecated now. Can anyone please help me to get the property to attach the quality profile at runtime.

I am using Sonar version 4.5.7. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 3):

It has been marked as deprecated with no replacement.

Quoting page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE43/Analysis+Parameters :

> Note that only parameters set through the UI are stored in the
>   database. For example, if you override the sonar.profile parameter via
>   command line for a specific project, it will not be stored in the
>   database. Local analyses in Eclipse, for example, would still be run
>   against the default quality profile.

And the latest version of the same page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters has link to ticket about deprecation that contains other details - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5370

In other words - profile should be configured via UI or using web services.